# Second Order ODE's with variable cofficients

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble solving the following ODE $$x^2\ddot{y}+2x\dot{y}-2y=0$$ The only other pieces of information I am given are that $y(1)=0$ and $y(2)=\frac{7}{2}$. I would attempt to use a variation of parameters but I do not have a known $y_1(t)$. Is it possible to solve this or am I missing a vital piece of information? Any help would be great!

Comment: this is euler DE, let $x=e^t$ for converting it to DE $y''+y'-2y=0$. See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try reduction of order since $y=x$ is a solution. Then try $y(x)={v(x)}{x}$

Or you can use this method..

$$x^2y''+2xy'-2y=0$$

Substitute $y=x^m$
$$m^2+m-2=0 \implies m_1=1,m_2=-2$$
then the solution is
$$y= {c_1}x^{m_1}+c_2x^{m_2}$$
$$y= {c_1}x+\frac {c_2}{x^2}$$

---

You can also integrate directly
$$x^2y''+2xy'-2y=0$$
$$y''+2\frac {(xy'-y)}{x^2}=0$$
$$y''+2(\frac yx)'=0$$
$$y'+\frac {2y}x=K_1$$
Which is of first order..

Comment: Thank you very much for that Isham! That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: yw @CMor.........